# Protection against Cross site scripting on specific JSP and Servlet code

Tags: xss, java

Here are the servelet cum JSP code, let me know how we could protect them from XSS?

Servlet Code:

```
String strRequestScrip = SecurityCheck.getStringParameter(request,PARAM_SCRIP_CODE);

 List arrScripLocator = MarketWatchUtils.getEqScripLocator(strRequestScrip, strExchangeCode, application);

 request.setAttribute("arrScripLocator", arrScripLocator);

 request.getRequestDispatcher("/ajax/ajaxScripLocator.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Jsp Code:

```
final List arrScripLocator = (List) request.getAttribute("arrScripLocator");

int intScripLocatorSize = arrScripLocator != null ? arrScripLocator.size() : 0;

intScripLocatorSize = intScripLocatorSize <= 20 ? intScripLocatorSize : 20;

out.print(intScripLocatorSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **[Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer)** to sanitize the request.
The code will look like this:

```
String unsafe ="<p><a href='http://example.com/' onclick='stealCookies()'>Link</a></p>";
String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());
// now: <p><a href="http://example.com/" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p>
```

I recommend you also read the [OWASP XSS Filter Evasion Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This would be great if I am able to help the IT admin.